# Debug visualizer - the visualizer dll can't be loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debuggervisualizer

I am learning to write a debug visualizer in vs2008 C#. But keep getting the error saying that MyDebugVisualizer dll can't be loaded when I am in debug mode and click the magnifying glass icon.

My app project is referencing the visualizer project. Before the type definition I have:

[DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(MyVisualizer))]
[Serializable]

I tried putting the visualizer dll in:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers
or
C:\Documents and Settings\zlee\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Visualizers

Is there something else missing?

Answer (score 1):

Is it signed?  Also are you trying to use the debug visualizer in the same host process as the application you are trying to debug?

Try compiling the visualizer and then just reference it by it's library and file location not the project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the fusion log tool to determine why the DLL is not loading?

[Fusion Log View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx)